# DataView class - get column id by name

Tags: google-apps-script, datatable, dataview

I'm using Google **DataView** class. Is there any way to find column's id
by its name?

DataView class has **getColumnLabel** method but I'm missing the method 
the could be named **getColumnIdByName**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to retrieve the column ID from the label.

  - I understood that `name` in your question is the label.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

In this answer, an object for retrieving the column ID from the label is prepared, because unfortunately, I couldn't find the method for directly retrieving the column ID from the label.

#### Sample script:

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  [{id: "id1", label: 'col1'}, {id: "id2", label: 'col2'}, {id: "id3", label: 'col3'}],
  ['1', 2,  3],
  ['2', 4, 6],
  ['3', 6, 9],
  ['4', 8, 12],
  ['5', 10, 15],
]);
var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

// Here, the object for searching the column ID is created.
var col = view.getNumberOfColumns();
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
  obj[view.getColumnLabel(i)] = view.getColumnId(i);
}

console.log(obj); // <--- {col1: "id1", col2: "id2", col3: "id3"}
console.log(obj["col3"]); // <--- id3
```

#### Note:

- In this case, if `['col1', {id: "id2", label: 'col2'}, {id: "id3", label: 'col3'}],` is used, `{col1: "", col2: "id2", col3: "id3"}` is returned. For example, if you don't want to include `col1: ""`, you can also use the following script.

  ```
  var col = view.getNumberOfColumns();
  var obj = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
    var id = view.getColumnId(i);
    if (id) {
      obj[view.getColumnLabel(i)] = id;
    }
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [DataView Class](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataview-class)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want I apologize. At that time, can you provide your current script? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I thought there is an additional method in the class that can be used to get the column id by name. Thank you for you help.